# how to export xlsx files with merged cells by similar information in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have this df:

| country | city |
| --- | --- |
| Canada | Montreal |
| Canada | Ottawa |
| Canada | Toronto |
| Argentina | Cordoba |
| Argentina | Mendoza |
| Chile | Santiago |

And I would like to create a xlsx file with something like

[image]

I know this is possible by entering manually the cells' reference, but I have a lot of countries, and this would be unsettling. Is there a way I can group the country variable in one merged cell?

here is a reproductible code:

```
tibble::tibble(
country = c('Canada','Canada','Canada','Argentina','Argentina','Chile'),
city = c('Montreal','Ottawa','Toronto','Cordoba','Mendoza','Santiago')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved via `openxlsx::mergeCells`. To this end I first create a list of the row indices to merge. Afterwards you could use e.g. `lapply` to loop over the list and merge the cells for each country.

```
library(openxlsx)

# Create list of rows to merge. Note: DF should be ordered by country
to_merge <- split(seq_len(nrow(dat)), dat$country)

fn <- tempfile(".xlsx")

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 1)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = dat)
lapply(to_merge, function(x) mergeCells(wb = wb, sheet = 1, cols = 1, rows = 1 + x))
saveWorkbook(wb, fn, overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]